# Setting instance variable in a Android View context class

Tags: android

I am trying to create a dynamic android layout with multiple views. The number of views are dependent on the items in a list.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/layout_category"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
          android:layout_marginTop="5px"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:padding="5dp" tools:context=".CategoryActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Category"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/></LinearLayout>
```

I inflate this `view` and then add to the `mainlayout`

```
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_category_view, null);
    mainLayout.addView(view)
```

The context class for the view `CategoryActivity` has a instance variable `categoryId`

I need to set the value this `categoryId` and refer it later i.e. during onClick action and then take appropriate action

in the CategoryActivity class i have duly mentioned

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_view);`

I have tried various ways but still not able to resolve and am stuck for good !

Comment: precisely what i was looking for... worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of dynamic views, you must use `getTag` and `setTag` methods to store and retrieve data into/from the views. See the below code based on your question:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_category_view, null);
view.setTag(categoryId);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int cat_id=(Integer)view.getTag();
            // do whatever you want to do further with it
        }
    });
mainLayout.addView(view);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
android:tag="MyInstanceVariable" 

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:tag="MyInstanceVariable" 
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"/>
```

you can add it dynamically

```
iv.setTag("MyInstanceVariable");
iv.setTag(R.String.Tag,"MyInstanceVariable");  //For multiple Tag
```

and you can access in java file like

```
  String tag = (String) iv.getTag();
  String tag = (String) iv.getTag(R.String.Tag);
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this